# This is giving a SyntaxError: invalid syntax pointing to in on the if statement. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: python

def solution(A):
for item in range(0, 1000000 + 1):
if item > 0:
if item not in A:
return item

A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]

print(solution(A))

Comment: And _what_ not in A?

Comment: You actually could write `0 < item not in A`, but I recommend you write the complete conditions in this case.

Comment: Also your indentation is messed up.

Comment: It would help if you could describe a bit of what is the expected output or in general what you are trying to achive.

Comment: If you don't want to consider `item == 0`, don't let it be 0 in the first place. `for item in range(1, 1000000):`

Comment: *print(solution)* will almost certainly not give the output you expect. The code is syntactically flawed in several respects. What is the intention here?

Comment: Please do not post the solution as an edit to the question, post it as a solution. Also, why did you remove the formatting?

Comment: Hi there, sorry about that, I am still figuring out how to use this, I didn't remove the formatting, I copy and paste and when I saved came out like that.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly state the item again after the and statement, so the line should be

```
if item > 0 and item not in A:
```

Also, you're missing logic within your `if` statement, there should be at least one line of indented code following it.